# Should questions marked as too broad have more suggestions on how to improve those questions?

Tags: discussion

I think it would be a good idea for anyone who marks a question as "too broad" have to give a small comment or explanation behind it. This would lead to better editing and higher quality questions instead of just locking a question out of being answered altogether. It's quite discouraging to have a question marked on hold when I myself think the question would have received good answers. What do you all think?

Comment: You can always edit the question to make it less *broad* and submit to get reopened.

Comment: Suggestions would be helpful to better edit the question.  I feel that some questions I ask are specific enough, but some others feel they aren’t. I just feel it would make asking questions less frustrating.

Comment: I believe this is a good idea, and I wonder even if the reason mustn't be mandatory, as from what I see regularly, "too broad" closure is often used to close questions that are not easy to answer, or require expertise in a domain that is not common. The consequence is that the stack revolves over sempiternal topics and doesn't expand. It was already mentioned earlier that "too broad" is not to be used for "I don't know the answer, and I don't know who could provide the answer".

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that this is necessary. The banner contains all the information and links you require:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.
>   If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please edit the question.

That link to the help center is not the help homepage - it is to a specific section about closed questions where more detail is avilable

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format

Any comments made when voting to close as too broad would simply duplicate that information in varying and opinionated ways.

Comment: "*Any comments made when voting to close as too broad would simply duplicate that information*". Not necessarily: "I'm voting... too broad because *an accurate answer cannot be provided if you don't specify a country*" etc.

Comment: @mins sure - that's being helpful and I'm not saying you shouldn't do that - I'm just saying its often unnecessary.